# Not getting sum of decimal property when use grouping in mongodb .net core

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I want the sum of one property from all documents but not getting the proper value because the property datatype is nullable decimal, when the property is an integer, the appropriate sum is getting.

```
var data1 = mongoCollection.Group(e => e.ClientId,
                g => new
                {
                    Total1 = g.Sum(e => e.Abc.Val1),
                    Total2 = g.Sum(e => e.Abc.Val2),
                    Total3 = g.Sum(e => e.Abc.Val3),
                    Total4 = g.Sum(e => e.Abc.Val4),        
                }).ToList();
```

Need help.

Comment: Try to provide the sample document, and expected and actual output to make the question helpful.

Comment: Thank you for showing interest @YongShun, I got the solution when I am saving the decimal values in MongoDB it saved as a string and that was the cause of not doing a summation of that values.

So we need to add [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)] attribute to the property of the c# class so that MongoDB can understand that this value is decimal.

Comment: Good to see you find the answer. Would recommend to **write as the answer**. Refer to: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Type%20in%20your%20answer%2C%20then,better%20solution%20to%20your%20problem!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB saves decimal values as strings when you save from .net core driver, that's why the sum is not doing because the value in MongoDB is string type.

You need to add `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]` attribute to the decimal property of the c# class so that MongoDB can understand that this value is decimal during saving data.

Or you can register BsonSerializer in the startup class like below which considers all decimal properties of the class for saving as a decimal.

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal), new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(decimal?), new NullableSerializer<decimal>(new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128)));
```